# Validação de campos

Tags: c#, conversão

Como eu poderia fazer a validação dos campos abaixo para que eles não fiquem em branco, pois minha maior dificuldade é que dois deles têm Convert.

```
NegocioFuncionario neg = new NegocioFuncionario();
EntidadeFuncionario ent = new EntidadeFuncionario();
ent.Matricula = Convert.ToInt32(txtMatricula.Text);
ent.DataNascimento = Convert.ToDateTime(txtNascimento.Text);
ent.Nome  = txtNome.Text;
ent.Situacao = cboSituacao.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: Coloque na parte de tag a linguagem que você esta usando.

Comment: Eu não sei qual liguagem você esta usando, mas acredito que um simples if solucionará o seu problema, ex: if(txtMatricula.Text == "" || txtMatricula.Text == null){ return false; }

Comment: Acredito que você esta trabalhando com C#, se for, pode fazer desta forma: if (txtMatricula.Text == string.Empty){ return false; }

Comment: Estou o usando o C# mesmo.

Porém, na hora de incluir esse comando dá sempre essa mensagem de erro  "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format", pois ela o campo txtMatricula está sendo convertido para string num primeiro momento.

Comment: Mas em que ponto você inserido o comando `if`?? Teria de ser antes da conversão, aí não terá problema.

Comment: Isso, antes da conversão, criei uma resposta com o código.

Comment: Você é um gênio, Wictor.
Meu problema foi solucionado com algo muito simples e prático. 
Valeu mesmo!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer a verificação desta forma:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MaterialTextBox.Text)) {
    // Mensagem para o usuário
    return false;
}
```

Utilizando o seu código:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtMatricula.Text)) {
    // Mensagem para o usuário
    return false;
}

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNascimento.Text)) {
    // Mensagem para o usuário
    return false;
}

NegocioFuncionario neg = new NegocioFuncionario();
EntidadeFuncionario ent = new EntidadeFuncionario();
ent.Matricula = Convert.ToInt32(txtMatricula.Text);
ent.DataNascimento = Convert.ToDateTime(txtNascimento.Text);
ent.Nome  = txtNome.Text;
ent.Situacao = cboSituacao.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156458/check-if-textbox-is-empty-and-return-messagebox